# Decoding an industrial date to date format

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a column that has a coded industrial date and I want to insert in another column the decoded data from that coded column there I have.

Coded data: 5000361,2002666,1036341, 2000316,2219009818 these are some exemples of coded data.
How can I decode that into data YYYY-MM-dd?

Comment: What is an *industrial date*? Which dates should be returned for your example data, what's the logic behind?

Comment: @dnoeth it's a date. If I have the 3 digits  from 2000316 it will by 316 or something like that and i want to transform that 316 in a full date (ex: day_of_year for 316 will be12-Nov-2019 (i want the data from this year)

Comment: Another ex: i have this select : sel td_day_of_week(date) from this year and this will be 339 and i want this 339 to be this date 2019-12-05

Comment: But 2002666 and 2219009818 clearly don't follow this pattern...

Comment: You have what looks to be 5 different patterns in your question.  For **each** of your examples, you will need to give us the desired result and logic to get it.

Comment: If your descriptiuon matches your data (your examples don't) you got a year plus the day of the year: `to_date('2019316', 'yyyyddd')`

Comment: I resolved This.. I just need to make an case (i think) to Take the year from a column named date_of_day where This coded date comes from the fluture..

Answer (score 0):

try:
select a, date(name of date column) from x;

worked for me once to get rid of time stamps from date column. might work for you as well.